# Django MySQL connection Error on windows Server

Tags: python, mysql, django, database

I have tried using
`pip install mysqlclient` and it says

Requirement already satisfied: mysqlclient in c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages (1.3.12)

I have MySQL installed with the connector as well

but when i try to `pip install MySQL-python`

It Throws an error. it says Failed building Wheel for MySQL-python...
it also throws this exception

try:
    import MySQLdb as Database
except ImportError as err:
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
        'Error loading MySQLdb module.\n'
        'Did you install mysqlclient?'
    ) from err

When i try to migrate the database, it doesnt migrate because it says mysql is not linked...

Comment: From your path it looks like you are running Python 3.7. Is that the case? mysqlclient might not yet work with this pre-release development version

Comment: When i went to File-> Settings->Project Interpreter, it says python 3.6

Comment: Ok, it was just a guess as your path says python37. Does the mysqlclient package show up in the list of packages in File -> Settings -> Project Interpreter (assuming you are using PyCharm as IDE)?

Comment: Ive installed Mysqlclient using `pip install C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BugTracker\mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl`
And it said that it already exists. And yes, i use PyCharm, and When i got to the project interpreter, it shows "Django 2.0.5, mysql-connector-python 8.0.11, pip 9.0.1, pytz 2018.4, setuptools 28.8.0

Comment: Huh? The name of the .whl says cp37 ... This is what I would expect in the name of the wheel for Python 3.7. This version does not even show up for me on pypi.org. Where did you get it from? If you are running Python 3.6 and have a mysqlclient package installed that was built for python 3.7, this might in fact cause your issue.

Comment: I shall try that when I get back and reply again once I try downloading the cp36 and let you know what happens

Comment: When i tried installing any of the official versions, im getting an error:
mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Any Suggestions?

Comment: But When i tried:

C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BugTracker>pip install C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BugTracker\mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Processing c:\inetpub\wwwroot\bugtracker\mysqlclient-1.3.12-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
Installing collected packages: mysqlclient
Successfully installed mysqlclient-1.3.12

Comment: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BugTracker>python --version
Python 3.7.0b4

Here it says im using python 3.7.0b4

but the interpreter is 3.6, How do i change it? What do i do?

Comment: I tried making the interpreter to python 3.7, Im getting more packages right now :
Django 2.0.5

Mysql-connector-python-rf

mysqlclient 1.3.12

pip 10.0.1
pytz 2018.4
setuptools 39.0.1
virtualenv 16.0.0
virtualenvwrapper-win 1.2.5
wheel 0.31.1

Comment: Try sorting out your Python versions. Identify all interpreters you have available on your PC. [Configure the desired interpreters accordingly in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html). Make sure you install packages for the interpreters where you need them, e.g. use PyCharm to install packages with the green plus sign to the right of the interpreter list. Make sure you actually run your software with the interpreter you linked to the project.

Comment: my venv folder has python36.dll.. So im supposed to be using 3.6, right?

Comment: If the project is configured to use that venv, yes. You'll want to make sure that a) you are aware which interpreter or venv will be used when your software runs "natively", i.e. outside of PyCharm in whatever can be considered your production environment, b) this interpreter or venv is also linked to the project and c) has the required packages installed. Is the venv you are referring to the same as the one that you use when calling Django's manage.py?

Comment: Yes it is, And i just noticed that in the terminal, it shows that I'm using 3.7.0b4 version of python and in my project venv, it uses python36.dll(C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BugTracker\venv\Scripts), and the interpreter is python 3.6 (C:\inetpub\wwwroot\BugTracker\venv\Scripts\python.exe)

Answer (score 2):

python37 doesn't support mysql yet.

Try this:

```
python3 -m pip install PyMySQL
```

Requirements

Python – one of the following:

- CPython >= 2.7 or >= 3.4
- Latest PyPy
- MySQL Server – one of the following:
- MySQL >= 5.5
- MariaDB >= 5.5

https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html